# Affdex SDK Ubuntu Compilation issues

Tags: android, c++, c, cmake, affdex-sdk

I am trying to compile the following wrapper library code to use the Affectiva library for Ubuntu:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <chrono>
#include <fstream>

#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/timer/timer.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options.hpp>

#include "VideoDetector.h"
#include "PhotoDetector.h"
#include "AffdexException.h"

#include "PlottingImageListener.hpp"
#include "StatusListener.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace affdex;

int main(int argsc, char * argsv) {
             std::map<boost::filesystem::path, bool> VIDEO_EXTS  = { {boost::filesystem::path(".avi"), 1},
                                                                     {boost::filesystem::path(".mov"), 1},
                                                                     {boost::filesystem::path(".flv"), 1},
                                                                     {boost::filesystem::path(".webm"), 1},
                                                                     {boost::filesystem::path(".wmv"), 1},
                                                                     {boost::filesystem::path(".mp4"), 1} };
             affdex::path DATA_FOLDER;
             affdex::path videoPath;

             int process_framerate = 30;
             bool draw_display = true;
             bool loop = false;
             unsigned int nFaces = 1;
             int faceDetectorMode = (int)FaceDetectorMode::LARGE_FACES;

             const int precision = 2;
             std::cerr.precision(precision);
             std::cout.precision(precision);

             namespace po = boost::program_options; // abbreviate namespace
             po::options_description description("Project for demoing the Affdex SDK VideoDetector class (processing video files).");
             description.add_options()
         #ifdef _WIN32
             ("data,d", po::wvalue< affdex::path >(&DATA_FOLDER)->default_value(affdex::path(L"data"), std::string("data")), "Path to the data folder")
             ("input,i", po::wvalue< affdex::path >(&videoPath)->required(), "Video file to processs")
         #else // _WIN32
             ("data,d", po::value< affdex::path >(&DATA_FOLDER)->default_value(affdex::path("data"), std::string("data")), "Path to the data folder")
             ("input,i", po::value< affdex::path >(&videoPath)->required(), "Video file to processs")
         #endif // _WIN32
             ("pfps", po::value< int >(&process_framerate)->default_value(30), "Processing framerate.")
             ("faceMode", po::value< int >(&faceDetectorMode)->default_value((int)FaceDetectorMode::SMALL_FACES), "Face detector mode (large faces vs small faces).")
             ("numFaces", po::value< unsigned int >(&nFaces)->default_value(1), "Number of faces to be tracked.")
             ("loop", po::value< bool >(&loop)->default_value(false), "Loop over the video being processed.")
             ;
             po::variables_map args;
             try
             {
                 po::store(po::command_line_parser(argsc, &argsv).options(description).run(), args);
                 if (args["help"].as<bool>())
                 {
                     std::cout << description << std::endl;
                     return 0;
                 }
                 po::notify(args);
             }
             catch (po::error& e)
             {
                 std::cerr << "ERROR: " << e.what() << std::endl << std::endl;
                 std::cerr << "For help, use the -h option." << std::endl << std::endl;
                 return 1;
             }

             // Parse and check the data folder (with assets)
             if (!boost::filesystem::exists(DATA_FOLDER))
             {
                 std::cerr << "Data folder doesn't exist: " << std::string(DATA_FOLDER.begin(), DATA_FOLDER.end()) << std::endl;
                 std::cerr << "Try specifying the folder through the command line" << std::endl;
                 std::cerr << description << std::endl;
                 return 1;
             }
             try
             {
                 std::shared_ptr<Detector> detector;

                 //Initialize out file
                 boost::filesystem::path csvPath(videoPath);
                 boost::filesystem::path fileExt = csvPath.extension();
                 csvPath.replace_extension(".csv");
                 std::ofstream csvFileStream(csvPath.c_str());

                 if (!csvFileStream.is_open())
                 {
                     std::cerr << "Unable to open csv file " << csvPath << std::endl;
                     return 1;
                 }

                 if (VIDEO_EXTS[fileExt]) // IF it is a video file.
                 {
                     detector = std::make_shared<VideoDetector>(process_framerate, nFaces, (affdex::FaceDetectorMode) faceDetectorMode);
                 }
                 else //Otherwise it's a photo
                 {
                     detector = std::make_shared<PhotoDetector>(nFaces, (affdex::FaceDetectorMode) faceDetectorMode);
                 }


                 //VideoDetector videoDetector(process_framerate, nFaces, (affdex::FaceDetectorMode) faceDetectorMode);



                 std::cout << "Max num of faces set to: " << detector->getMaxNumberFaces() << std::endl;
                 std::string mode;
                 switch (detector->getFaceDetectorMode())
                 {
                     case FaceDetectorMode::LARGE_FACES:
                         mode = "LARGE_FACES";
                         break;
                     case FaceDetectorMode::SMALL_FACES:
                         mode = "SMALL_FACES";
                         break;
                     default:
                         break;
                 }

                 std::cout << "Face detector mode set to: " << mode << std::endl;
                 shared_ptr<PlottingImageListener> listenPtr(new PlottingImageListener(csvFileStream, draw_display));

                 detector->setDetectAllEmotions(true);
                 detector->setDetectAllExpressions(true);
                detector->setDetectAllEmojis(true);
                 detector->setDetectAllAppearances(true);
                 detector->setClassifierPath(DATA_FOLDER);
                 detector->setImageListener(listenPtr.get());


                 detector->start();    //Initialize the detectors .. call only once

                 do
                 {
                     shared_ptr<StatusListener> videoListenPtr = std::make_shared<StatusListener>();
                     detector->setProcessStatusListener(videoListenPtr.get());
                     if (VIDEO_EXTS[fileExt])
                     {
                         ((VideoDetector *)detector.get())->process(videoPath); //Process a video
                     }
                     else
                     {
                        //videoPath is of type std::wstring on windows, but std::string on other platforms.
                        cv::Mat img = cv::imread(std::string(videoPath.begin(), videoPath.end()));

                         // Create a frame
                         Frame frame(img.size().width, img.size().height, img.data, Frame::COLOR_FORMAT::BGR);

                         ((PhotoDetector *)detector.get())->process(frame); //Process an image
                     }

                     do
                     {
                         if (listenPtr->getDataSize() > 0)
                         {
                             std::pair<Frame, std::map<FaceId, Face> > dataPoint = listenPtr->getData();
                             Frame frame = dataPoint.first;
                             std::map<FaceId, Face> faces = dataPoint.second;


                             if (draw_display)
                             {
                                 listenPtr->draw(faces, frame);
                             }

                             std::cerr << "timestamp: " << frame.getTimestamp()
                             << " cfps: " << listenPtr->getCaptureFrameRate()
                             << " pfps: " << listenPtr->getProcessingFrameRate()
                             << " faces: "<< faces.size() << endl;

                             listenPtr->outputToFile(faces, frame.getTimestamp());
                         }
                     } while (VIDEO_EXTS[fileExt] && (videoListenPtr->isRunning() || listenPtr->getDataSize() > 0));
                 } while(loop);

                 detector->stop();
                 csvFileStream.close();

                 std::cout << "Output written to file: " << csvPath << std::endl;
             }
             catch (AffdexException ex)
             {
                 std::cerr << ex.what();
             }

             return 0;
}
```

My command is:

```
g++-4.8 VidDetector.cpp -o VidDetector -std=c++11 -I/root/affdex-sdk/include -I/root/affdexUbuntu/include -I/root/sdk-samples/common -L/root/affdex-sdk/lib -l affdex-native -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -l boost_system -l boost_filesystem
```

The result is an issue with linking the boost library:

```
VidDetector.cpp:(.text+0x8d9): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::variables_map::variables_map()'

VidDetector.cpp:(.text+0x943): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::store(boost::program_options::basic_parsed_options<char> const&, boost::program_options::variables_map&, bool)'

VidDetector.cpp:(.text+0x9e5): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::operator<<(std::ostream&, boost::program_options::options_description const&)'

VidDetector.cpp:(.text+0xa0b): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::notify(boost::program_options::variables_map&)'

VidDetector.cpp:(.text+0xb1a): undefined reference to `boost::program_options::operator<<(std::ostream&, boost::program_options::options_description const&)'

/tmp/ccUPvUA2.o: In function `boost::program_options::error_with_option_name::~error_with_option_name()':
```

I am not sure how to resolve these issues. I have tried including the boost .so files with g++ but it still is not finding the references to the necessary files. What am I missing in the command that will fix this issue?

Comment: You forgot to link with `boost_program_options` library.

Comment: did the comment by @Tsyvarev resolve this?

Comment: it did not. I am not sure what version to use.

Comment: The app was built with boost-1.55 , sorry I think you ran into a bug on the README.